# Servers contacting WSUS server but not reporting status

Tags: updates, windows-server-2016, wsus

I have a domain that contains only Windows Server 2016 Standard servers.  Most of the servers are contacting the WSUS server but are not reporting their status.  There are 40 servers and for 33 of them, the last status report date and time is the date and time when I went into each one and manually ran **wuauclt /reportnow**.  The last contact date is less than 24 hours for the majority of the servers.

All of the servers have the same policy: Download updates each night at 10pm and wait for an administrator to install them.

The WSUS server itself is showing as having all available updates.  It's running version 10.0.14393.2007 of Update Services.  I've rebooted the WSUS server, I've added more space to the disk where WSUS is located and I've run the Server Cleanup Wizard and none of those things have made a difference.

What else can I do to try to make the servers report status to the WSUS server?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I changed the values of the WSUS Application Pool in IIS (Advanced Settings) and all 2016 servers.
Queue Length: 25000 from 1000
Limit Interval (minutes): 15 from 5
"Service Unavailable" Response: TcpLevel from HttpLevel